# How to remove multiple results from admin grid in ui-component Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, custom-admin-grid

How to Remove the multiple results in the grid from the same date in admin grid UI component Magento 2
- I have got multiple results for 1 day. 
- I need a single result for a single date.

```
<column name="creation_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">140</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```